# Проблема при использовании необязательного параметра MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

Требуется выводить список товаров, которые были проданы в определенный промежуток времени (SaleDate использует тип данных datetime), но второй даты может не быть, в таком случае требуется вывести список товаров только за тот день, который был указан в параметрах. В моем случае, если введен один параметр, то sql-запрос ничего не возвращает, но если указать два параметра, то все возвращается успешно. Я не совсем понимаю, почему это происходит. Код:

```
@FirstDate date,
@SecondDate date = NULL
as
if (@SecondDate IS NULL)
select Product.Title, Manufacturer.[Name], ProductSale.SaleDate, (Product.Price * ProductSale.Quantity) AS 'Total Earn' from
ProductSale join Product on Product.ID = ProductSale.ProductID join Manufacturer on Manufacturer.ID = Product.ManufacturerID
where SaleDate = @FirstDate
else if (select count(*) from ProductSale where SaleDate between @FirstDate and @SecondDate) != 0
select Product.Title, Manufacturer.[Name], ProductSale.SaleDate, (Product.Price * ProductSale.Quantity) AS 'Total Earn' from
ProductSale join Product on Product.ID = ProductSale.ProductID join Manufacturer on Manufacturer.ID = Product.ManufacturerID
where SaleDate between @FirstDate and @SecondDate
else if (select count(*) from ProductSale where SaleDate between @FirstDate and @SecondDate) = 0
print 'Товаров не найдено!' 

exec PR_2DATES '16.03.2024'



| Title | Name | SaleDate | TotalEarn |
```

Comment: `WHERE SaleDate BETWEEN @FirstDate AND COALESCE(@SecondDate, @FirstDate)`

Comment: @Akina переписал запрос, теперь срабатывает условие else, если вводить 1 дату. Если вводить две, то все работает. Код запроса ниже

Comment: `create or alter proc PR_2DATES
@FirstDate date,
@SecondDate date = NULL
as
if (select count(*) from ProductSale where SaleDate between @FirstDate and COALESCE(@SecondDate, @FirstDate)) != 0
select Product.Title, Manufacturer.[Name], ProductSale.SaleDate, (Product.Price * ProductSale.Quantity) AS 'Total Earn' from
ProductSale join Product on Product.ID = ProductSale.ProductID join Manufacturer on Manufacturer.ID = Product.ManufacturerID
where SaleDate between @FirstDate and COALESCE(@SecondDate, @FirstDate)
else 
print 'Товаров не найдено!'

exec PR_2DATES '16.03.2024'`

Comment: 'if (@SecondDate IS NULL)' теперь не нужно

Comment: @rotabor я убрал эту строку, оставил только if, else

Comment: Я имелл ввиду ветку, т. е. нужно убрать "if (@SecondDate IS NULL)
select Product.Title, Manufacturer.[Name], ProductSale.SaleDate, (Product.Price * ProductSale.Quantity) AS 'Total Earn' from
ProductSale join Product on Product.ID = ProductSale.ProductID join Manufacturer on Manufacturer.ID = Product.ManufacturerID
where SaleDate = @FirstDate
else".

Comment: @rotabor я ее и убрал. не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут проблема в том, что "between @FirstDate and @SecondDate" - это, условно, 0, если @FirstDate и @SecondDate одно и то же. Поэтому нужно добавить одни сутки:

```
COALESCE(@SecondDate, DATEADD(day,1,@FirstDate))
```